# How to print 1st,3nd,5th elements in JSON array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I triied to get data from other web site and convert it in to json array.

following code used for it.

```
foreach($models1 as $mod)
{
    $result[] = array('model'=> $mod);

}

$finalResultArray = array(
        'mobiles' => $result
);

echo json_encode($finalResultArray);
```

then the result was

> {"mobiles":[{"model":"Apple iPhone 5c 16GB"},{"model":"93,000"},{"model":"Apple iPhone 5s 16GB"},{"model":"117,312"},{"model":"Apple iPhone 5 32GB"},{"model":"94,280"},{"model":"Apple iPhone 4S 16GB"},{"model":"82,000"},{"model":"Apple iPhone 5 16GB"},{"model":"93,000"}]}

I want to print this array as like this

> {"mobiles":[{"model":"Apple iPhone 5c 16GB"},{"model":"Apple iPhone 5s 16GB"},{"model":"Apple iPhone 5 32GB"},{"model":"Apple iPhone 4S 16GB"},{"model":"Apple iPhone 5 16GB"}]}

i want to remove {"model":"93,000"},{"model":"117,312"} etc... from this JSON array

Can any one help me...????

Comment: 1. Your question title sounds like FizzBuzz. http://rosettacode.org/wiki/FizzBuzz  2. Filtering remote data by numeric index is a recipe for disaster, what happens when the data changes? Your code becomes worthless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it has been seen in your question , you want to remove the odd index number array values.

```
$i = 0;
foreach($models1 as $mod)
{
    if(($i % 2) == 0) {
        $result[] = array('model'=> $mod);
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will only insert the even numbers, not the odd ones.

Comment: @Fluffeh OP wants to insert the even number values, See `{"model":"93,000"},{"model":"117,312"}` are in odd index number.

Comment: I read "I want to remove {"model":"93,000"},{"model":"117,312"} etc... from this JSON array" as the opposite of that, meaning he didn't want them in there?

Comment: @Fluffeh Yes OP wants to remove that odd index number values. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the way you make the array, it will be simple enough to do using a modulus operator as follows:

```
$i=0;
foreach($models1 as $mod)
{
    if(($i+1)%2==1)
    {
        $result[] = array('model'=> $mod);
    }
    $i++;
}
```

This will only insert the odd numbers into the array to start off with. If you want to have all the entries in the array but only display the odd ones, you can easily modify this example to output only what you need.

Comment: where are you incrementing `$i`?

Comment: @plainjane Ahhh yes, it's right there (after I hastily added it) :P

Answer (score 0):

Solutions provided above are actually fine, however though it [array_filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function so that you can do more sophisticated filtering than just "every odd model" easily...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this convert json to array, skip the odd values, and store in an array and again convert array to json

```
    foreach($models1 as $key => $value)
    {
        if($key%2 == 0)
        {
            $arr_new['mobiles'][] = $value;
        }
    }
    $json_new = json_encode($arr_new);
    echo $json_new;
```

The output is as below

```
       {"mobiles":[{"model":"Apple iPhone 5c 16GB"},{"model":"Apple iPhone 5s 16GB"},{"model":"Apple iPhone 5 32GB"},{"model":"Apple iPhone 4S 16GB"},{"model":"Apple iPhone 5 16GB"}]}
```

Answer (score -1):

If the rule is just to **remove elements with odd keys** then try this:

```
// This loop keeps elements with index 0, 2, 4 ... and so on
for ($i=0;$i<count($models1);$i=$i+2){
  $finalResultArray['mobiles'][] = array('model' => $models1[$i]);
} 

echo json_encode($finalResultArray);
```